# ARITHABORT with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

I am running below query to get comma separated value and this working fine on my environment but when I tried to run this in client environment, I got error SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect settings: 'ARITHABORT'. Verify that SET options are correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type methods and/or spatial index operations.

```
$rolesrequirement = Connection::queryBuilder()
            ->select("max(c.title) as title, STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(rc.roleid AS VARCHAR(10)) [text()]
                     FROM edoc_link_role_competence as rc  
                     WHERE rc.competenceid = c.id 
                     FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
                    .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') as roleid")
            ->from('edoc_competence', 'c')
            ->leftJoin('c', 'edoc_link_role_competence', 'rc', 'rc.competenceid = c.id')
            ->where('c.installationid = :id')
            ->groupBy('c.id')
            ->setParameter(':id', $iid)->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

I am using MSSQL -2010  and on client env its 2008
Can anybody have same experience_?

Comment: can you please share the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting ARITHABORT ON at server level.
Try below link for help.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mikkole/2014/01/02/queries-failing-because-of-the-arithabort-setting/